# Determine the three digits of a number.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A three-digit number in base 7 is expressed by the same numerals, but in reverse order on the basis 9. Determine the three digits.

Comment: I know  (abc) _7 = a*7^2 + b*7 + c and also (cba) _9 = c*9^2 + b*9 + a. I think we have to try to match it there somehow.

Comment: Uou mean, perhaps, with an equal sign?

Comment: As there are $294$ three digit base 7 numbers, you can just try them all.

Comment: I was not assimilating that (abc) _7 = (cba) _9. Now I think I will. = D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: If the digits in base $7$ are $a$, $b$, $c$, then $49a+7b+c=81c+9b+a$.

A little rearranging gives $b=24a-40c$.  So $b=8(3a-5c)$.  Of course not very many multiples of $8$ are digits in base $7$.